# Radiation in particle accelerators

Tags: accelerator-physics, particle-accelerators

I was reading about particle accelerators in Wikipedia and I came across this.

> Depending on the energy and the particle being accelerated, circular accelerators suffer a disadvantage in that the particles emit synchrotron radiation.

Why don't linear accelerators have this disadvantage. The particle is accelerated in both the cases right?

Comment: http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node131.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Larmor's formula for total synchrotron power is:

$$ P =  \frac{q^2}{6\pi\epsilon_0 c}\gamma^6\big[|\dot{\vec \beta}|^2-|{\vec \beta}\times\dot{\vec \beta}|^2\big]$$

which is easily separated into longitudinal and transverse components.

But the real issue is that in a LINAC, the electron passes through the accelerator (like SLAC) once in 1 microsecond and then hits the target/beam dump. Meanwhile, and electron at LEP goes around more than 11,000 times per second and is continually loosing energy.

At DESY, the positron beam lifetime was on the order of 8 hours (last time I was there), so the energy lost to synchrotron radiation is significant.

Comment: Note that Larmor's (Liénard's?) equation implies that a particle moving in a straight line at a given speed will actually emit *more* power than a particle moving in a circle at that same speed.  The OP's Wikipedia quote is actively misleading in that regard.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I noticed that the transverse term subtracts from the longitudinal term, so it appears to decrease the total magnitude; however, the "dot" is over the "vector" sign for $\beta=v/c$. In the lab frame, that is basically stuck close to "1", even for huge linear accelerations. While even a small bend can make both terms significant A more detailed answer should address that.